# Como chamar uma função de uma dll já injetada(c++)?

Tags: c++, dll

como faço para chamar uma função dentro de uma dll já injetada no processo?
exemplo: eu gostaria de quando eu apertar um botão no form que eu criei, chamasse a função asmFunction();
se eu chamo a função dentro do Main_Thread funciona muito bem, mas tenho duvido para fazer isso 
aqui esta o código da minha dll.

```
#include <Windows.h>
extern int UiMain();
DWORD WINAPI Main_Thread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    UiMain();
    return S_OK;
}
void asmFunction(DWORD x,DWORD y,DWORD adressToCall) {
    __asm {
        push x
            push y
            call adressToCall
    };
}
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,DWORD _reason,LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (_reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        CreateThread(0, 0x1000, &Main_Thread, 0, 0, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: você só precisa referenciar a função e chama-la em algum lugar do código. Igual se faz com o `.h`